# Different result on calling a method through anonymous block and from LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, callout

I am calling a method imperatively from lwc and its not giving the same result when I am calling same code though anonymous block. Below is my class and when I am calling the method from anonymous block its giving response as `System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]` but while running from lwc its giving `System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401]`.

```
public with sharing class MessageController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Integer fetchUnreadMessages(){
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        request.setEndpoint('https://'+URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost()+'/services/data/v48.0/chatter/users/'+UserInfo.getUserId()+'/conversations/unread-count');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        string autho = 'Bearer '+userInfo.getSessionId();
        request.setHeader('Authorization', autho);
        response = http.send(request);
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            system.debug('****RESPONSE::'+results.get('unreadCount'));
            return Integer.valueOf(results.get('unreadCount'));
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lightning Session ID doesn't include REST API privileges, except for a few UI-API calls. You should be able to use the [ConnectApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_connect_api.htm) classes to get the information you want for Chatter, or you can use a Named Credential to allow Apex access to the API.

Answer (score 0):

You also have the option to get sessionId from VF page.

Define a VF page

```
<apex:page contentType="application/json">
    {!$Api.Session_ID}
</apex:page>
```

then in your apex add a method to get the session id from the vf page

```
   public static String getSessionIdFromVFP() {
        return Page.SessionIdFromVFP.getContent().toString();
    }
```

And in your `fetchUnreadMessages` method call `getSessionIdFromVFP` to get the session id.

```
    string autho = 'Bearer '+getSessionIdFromVFP();
    request.setHeader('Authorization', autho);
    response = http.send(request);
```